# Example of an integral domain in which every quadratic polynomial with a root in its fraction field splits into linear factors

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am solving an exercise from the book on Algebraic Number Theory by S. Alaca and K. Williams. The problem asks to give an example of an integral domain $D$ such that every quadratic polynomial which has roots in its field of fraction, splits into linear factors in $D$.

Apart from fields, which is a trivial example, I am trying to find some non-trivial examples. On an inspection of the paper named "Quadratic Polynomials and Unique Factorisation" by W. C. Waterhouse I found that the ring of algebraic integers, denoted by $\mathbb{A}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is such an example. I am unable to prove this.

The property, in this case, boils down to show that every quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{A}$ splits. I need help for showing this.

Also I would like to get an example of such a domain other that $\mathbb{A}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, $\mathbb{Z}$ is an example, by Gauss's Lemma.

Gauss's Lemma says that a product of primitive polynomials is primitve (a polynomial is *primitive* if the gcd of its coefficients is $1$). As a corollary, we have that:

> If $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is primitive, and $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g,h\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then there exist polynomial $G(x),H(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\deg(G)=\deg(g)$, $\deg(H)=\deg(h)$ such that $f(x)=G(x)H(x)$.

In particular: if $f(x)$ is a primitive quadratic polynomial, $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, which has roots in $\mathbb{Q}$, then we may factor it in $\mathbb{Q}$ as $f(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = (ax-ar_1)(x-r_2)$. By the corollary to  Gauss's Lemma, there exist polynomial $g(x),h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, both of degree $1$, such that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$; that is, $f(x)$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, as desired.

Note that the roots need not be in $\mathbb{Z}$ (unless the polynomial is monic, in which case they *definitely* are).

For an arbitrary, not necessarily primitive polynomial, write $f(x) = dF(x)$, where $d$ is the content and $F(x)$ is primitive; roots of $f(x)$ are roots of $F(x)$, so we can factor $F(x)$ as $F(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ of degree $1$ whenever $F(x)$ has roots in $\mathbb{Q}$; then $f(x)=(dg(x))h(x)$ is a factorization for $f(x)$ into linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}$.

A proof that every polynomial with algebraic integer coefficients splits into  (not necessarily monic) linear factors can be found in this [paper of David McKinnon and myself from the Monthly](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037491).

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed to check $\mathbb{Z}$ before going for $\mathbb{A}$. I will look into your paper and let you know if I am stuck at any point.